# Error message using the acor Python module

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to run some code which uses a python module `acor`.

When I run my code I get the error:

`AttributeError: module 'acor' has no attribute 'acor'`

The only thing I can find online about this is [this link](https://github.com/dfm/acor/issues/5). Someone suggest a fix in which:

`import _acor` is replaced by
`import acor._acor as _acor`.

I tried this, but I still get the same error. I am using `Python 3.9.7`

Comment: As indicated in [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") a Good Question requires:  
- A title that summarizes the specific problem  
- An Introduction to your problem which provides the context of your problem and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.    
- The simplest data and code which reproduces your problem in a form that a respondent can copy and paste into their environment.  
- reserve images things that are otherwise impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: The code I'm trying to run - calls a giant eco system of other codes that weren't written by me and are somewhat of a black box. I therefore can't post code that reproduces the problem, I'm just hoping someone may recognise the problem from the little information I have. I'm given every detail that I have available to me, what I've done and what I've found. If that's not enough for anyone to help then that's okay.

Comment: The fix suggested works fine for me. Did you also replace ``import acor`` to ``import acor._acor as acor`` in your script ?

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean when you say "also"? Making that replacement is the only thing that I did...

Comment: @user1551817 In my case, here is what I did: I opened ``acor.py`` located in ``venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/acor/acor.py``, and replaced the line 5 with ``import acor._acor as _acor``. In my main.py script (where I imported acor), I replaced ``import acor`` with ``import acor._acor as acor``. Note that you'll have to replace all accor imports in your project.

Comment: Do you have a file named `acor.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing the version of `acor` available via Pip, and the one available on Github, it appears that the two versions are not identical, exclusively in `__init__.py` and `acor.py` files. See [here](https://github.com/dfm/acor/commit/b55eb8efa7df6c73b6f3f0c9b64fa1c801e8f821) for the changes.

In order to avoid the error `AttributeError: module 'acor' has no attribute 'acor'`, you should use the version available on Github, which contains the fix.

### Method 1

You can install the version via the source code available on Github.

Uninstall the current version:

```
pip uninstall acor
```

Clone the git repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/dfm/acor.git
```

Compile and install `acor`:

```
cd acor
python setup.py install
```

### Method 2

You can also make the changes manually.

Identify the location of the `acor` module:

```
python -c "import acor; print(acor.__path__)"
```

Modify `acor.py` and `__init__.py` located in this folder:

`__init__.py` line 9:

```
from .acor import *
```

`acor.py` line 5:

```
from . import _acor
```